# How to adjust footer resp. header correctly?

Tags: header-footer

Just have a little question about the footer and header of a document. I do not really know how  to adjust them so that there is enough space between the header resp. footer and the text. I do have an exemple in the code below. Is it right like this, or should I increase the space. What is normal? For any reason the footer is very low (I suppose it is because of the footenote settings I have made. If you leave out, it seems normally. How may I make it normal looking?)
I hope someone may help me. Thank you for your help!!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=25mm} 

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} %Spacing

%Footnote
\usepackage[hang,splitrule]{footmisc}
\addtolength{\footskip}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.4cm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\fancyhf{} % clear the headers
\fancyhead[R]{%
   % We want italics
   \itshape
   % The chapter number only if it's greater than 0
   \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \chaptername\ \thechapter. \fi
   % The chapter title
   \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for the mock text

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\kant

\mainmatter

\chapter*{Another introduction}
\chaptermark{Another introduction}

\kant

\chapter{Title}

\kant

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really, it depends on the printing. Can it print so near the edge? Most modern printers can. I think it looks a bit off. I think I'd just remove the `\addtolength{\footskip}{0.5cm}`-part, and put the page number on the outer margin, if `twoside`-printing should be enabled. Also, when using `twoside`, inner/outer-margins should in most cases not be the same. All this is of course just my opinion, and really,  this is not the right place for opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read section "2.1. Fundamentals of Page Layout" in the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf).

Here is a suggestion using KOMA possibilities for a twosided document. Note that you can use `\addchap` if you want an unnumbered chapter with TOC and header entry.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt,
  headheight=16.5pt,
  DIV=12,
  headinclude,
  numbers=enddot
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} %Spacing

%Footnote
\usepackage[hang,splitrule]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.4cm}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\chapapp\ \thechapter\autodot\enskip}

\usepackage{blindtext} % dummy text

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext

\mainmatter
\addchap{Another introduction}
\Blindtext[20]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]